# How to get correct JSON response from my app on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, django, heroku, fetch

I have a test Django application on Heroku what returns this by `/api/test/?format=json` request

[image: p1]

And I try to get it in frontend part whith this code

```
let url = "https://morning-thicket-20719.herokuapp.com";

async function getData() 
{
    let response = await fetch(url + '/api/test/?format=json');
    let data = await response;
    return data;
}

getData().then(data => console.log(data));
```

and get in console this message:

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://morning-thicket-20719.herokuapp.com/api/test/?format=json'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

[image: p2]

How to solve this problem? Is it in my Django app?

Comment: Have you read up on how to implement CORS handling in Django?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I haven't read. You think this is the problem?

Comment: Well that's what the message is telling you, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get and parse your response into JSON: In body of your response object, there's a method called `.json()`. Call this method on your response object.

Your code now becomes:

```
let url = "https://morning-thicket-20719.herokuapp.com";

async function getData() 
{
    let response = await fetch(url + '/api/test/?format=json');
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

getData()
 .then(data => console.log(data))
 .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error!");
    console.error(err);
  });
```

And also you have to enable CORS in your app on heroku.

**Steps to Enable CORS**
Take the following steps to enable CORS for Rest API hosted in Django application. I assume you already have REST API developed and hosted.

- Install django-cors-headers using PIP as follows:

  `pip install django-cors-headers`
- Add corsheaders to installed applications in **settings.py**:

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
      ...
      'corsheaders',
  ]
  ```
- Add corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware to middleware section in **settings.py**:

  ```
  MIDDLEWARE = [
      'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
      ...

  ]
  ```
- Allow access to all domains by setting the following variable to TRUE in settings.py:

  ```
  CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
  ```

Alternatively, you can specify which domains must be given access by creating following variables in **settings.py**:

```
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
    CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
           'http://localhost:4200',
    ]
```

That's all you have to do to access resources of django application from other applications hosted on other servers.

Comment: `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` might be list, so there must be "[" and "]" not round brackets

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, little typos. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For the cors issue, do this

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

and then add it to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

You might also want to browse the configuration section of its documentation https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#configuration paying particular attention to the various CORS_ORIGIN_ settings.

Comment: Should probably add a note about the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` or `CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST` setting

Comment: Should I create `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` if it dosn't exist and why the brackets are round?

Comment: If you are using a newer version of Django the setting will be named `MIDDLEWARE`

Comment: If your installed django is < 1.10 , use the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES ` else `MIDDLEWARE`

Comment: Yes, I'm using Django > 1.10 so I add it to `MIDDLEWARE`. Thx guys, it works by setting `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` to `True`